# Flair 500 Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, flair, 500-server-error

My flair was working fine yesterday, but for approximately the past day, my Stack Overflow flair has been broken. My flair also works fine on Super User and on other Stack Exchange sites, and I can see other people's flair. Even my network wide flair works, but my Stack Overflow flair does not work. On my user page, I see this:

[image: flair list]

Here is my flair image:

[image: flair]

When I try to visit the [url for my flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1721527.png), I get a 500 (Internal Server Error)

Can anyone else see this issue?

**EDIT: [My flair on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/14461/jdwire/flair) is broken too.** (Not that I have much rep there)

Comment: Have you uploaded a custom profile then revert back to a gravatar?

Comment: @Oded I don't think I have, but I may have done it by accident once. I can't remember. Also, this started happening in the past day, and I know I haven't changed my avatar in the past day.

Comment: SO started to hate you. :-/

Comment: Same problem for me - http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/298479.png

Comment: [My flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/447356.png) is fine...

Comment: Same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1085891.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made some assumptions regarding profile images (to do with the new uploadable profile images).

These assumptions were wrong is some cases... I just pushed a fix, and your flair is all back and shiny.

You may need to refresh the browser cache before seeing the glory of your flair.