# Flair: 500 Internal Server Error - http://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/flair/378431.png

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, 500-server-error

My question is the same as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170997/197176).

I put my stackexchange flair at the bottom of my sites:

- http://twigfiddle.com/help
- http://domajax.com/

And get a "profile for Ninsuo on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites" link instead of my nice flair.

By opening Firebug, I can read the following error:

[image]

Or as text:

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error -
> https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/flair/378431.png

I did not tried to update a new picture - just in case you want to get further first.

Good luck!

Comment: @Oded Have we got a ETA on this issue ?

Comment: @DamianNikodem - should be fixed already